# Экспорт из Java в doc/docx

Tags: jasperreports, java, doc

Нужно создать из **java** приложения несколько страничек в **ворде**. Страницы будут содержать картинки и текст. Без графиков и т.п.
Идеалом было бы в красивом и оформленном шаблоне менять текст и картинки.

Курил гугл - вот что нашёл:

- **javadocx**
  Создаёт в **docx**. Очень странная библиотека. Не понял как вставить картинку, хотя текст успешно вставил
- **Apache POI**
  Создаёт **doc**. Видно что ребята старались. Вставил текст кое-как. Ворд говорит документ повреждён =( Хотя OpenOffice открыл и прочёл текст. К картинкам даже страшно притрагиваться
- **Генераторы отчётов** (Jasper)
  Создаёт а потом экспортирует в **PDF**, **Docx** и кучу других.Очень перспективно для моей задачи. Но не понял как по простому (без баз данных и всех крутых штук) записать нужные данные в отчёт и экспортить его в docx

Если у кого есть какие примеры, наработки советы - welcome
Также приветствую другие подходы к решению задачи =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мы в свое время на одном проекте использовали [**docx4j**](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j) для генерации вордовских документов. Деталей реализации не помню, но проблем особых не возникало. На сайте библиотеки есть хорошая вики и ссылки на статьи. Попробуйте это решение, может подойдет.

Comment: Есть примеры как добавлять/редактировать ? Чёт не вкуриваю как )

Comment: Читайте же вики, там все написано) [samples](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j/browser/trunk/docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples)

Answer (score 1):

Не так давно пришлось делать документ с таблицами. В таблицах должны были заполнятся определенные ячейки, остальной текст шаблона практически неизменный, и кое где нужно было тоже вставлять текст (ФИО, должность и т.п.). Попробовал JasperReports, но он не подошел для моих нужд. JasperReports сгенерировал из тестового шаблона документ (я пробовал doc, docx и rtf), составленный очень странным образом - таблиц в нем не было, были лишь отдельные shape с текстом. Это меня не устроило. Поэтому я воспользовался [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) и составил шаблон документа в  RTF.

Answer (score 0):

А бы еще дополнительно спросил, что вы потом с этим документом делать будете.
`jasperreports` могут импортировать в несколько форматов сразу, включая `DOCX`. Не знаю как 4-й, но я работал с 3-м, и он немного криво экспортировал в `DOCX`. Эти `DOCX`-файлы можно только просматривать, из-за своеобразного построения содержимого документа на основе таблицы. Большой плюс `jasperreports` в том, что есть визуальный конструктор отчетов. Т.е. построить какой-нибудь отчет составляет труда почти также, как и в `Microsoft Access`. Остальное уже так: либо программно заполняете содержание отчета, либо в XML-коде, средствами `jasperreports`. Мне лично импонирует больше именно `jasperreports` благодаря именно быстрому построению отчетов и большим количеством возможностей библиотеки, а также возможность полного программного управления заполнением элементов отчета.

Что касается `Apache POI`, то да, в `DOC` он плохо экспортирует. Но я не скажу такого о `DOCX`. В формат `DOCX`, `Apache POI` экспортирует хорошо. Тут можно полностью программно сделать форматирование текста, все отступы, свойства и т.д. Короче, документ будет в конечном итоге выглядеть как вручную написанный человеком. Т.е. доступный для легкого редактирования и изменения. Но тут уж очень сложно. Надо много помучаться, чтобы создать хороший и отформатированный документ.

Comment: А если сделать красивый doc самому а потом просто менять нужные блоки ?

Answer (score 0):

Aspose.Words for Java

Comment: Платное же - будут копирайты (